# NumberPicker does not show values past the initial state

Tags: android, numberpicker

I'm new to Android and I am implementing a numberpicker in one of my activities. Here's my code:

```
picker = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.order_confirm_bring_time_minute_picker);
picker.setMinValue(15);
picker.setMaxValue(120);
picker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

picker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
        Calendar tc = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+9:00"));
        tc.setTimeInMillis(minimum.getTimeInMillis());
        if(newVal - 15 > 0)
            tc.add(Calendar.MINUTE, newVal - 15);

        ampm.setText(timeFormat.format(tc.getTime()));
    }
});
```

What I'm trying to do is to have my number picker show values between 15 and 120 and use this as a "minute from now" to calculate and to show on my TextView `ampm`. However, this is what I see from my view.

[image: initial state of my number picker]

[image: after the value has been changed via scrolling]

The upper image is what it looks like when the activity with NumberPicker is first displayed. The one below is when the value has been changed. From what gets displayed in my `ampm` TextView, I can see that the listener is doing its work. I even tried setting the value of `picker` as `newVal` in my listener with no luck.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Have you tested this on different devices? When exactly does the pciker number disappear - onClick, when you set your value or when you release the click..?

Comment: @Amy I have tested on three different devices each of API 21, 19, and 17 if the API levels should matter, which I'm not sure of. I'm assuming it disappears as the edittext loses focus?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me. the number in deed was always there, just white font on white background. It seemed to be gone because the focus was lost, hence the hightlight gone.